# Office UI Fabric React Word Addin some icons are not showing

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I found 3 sets of icons on the web for Fabric:

1. [Developer documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/styles/web/icons), select the "Fabric Core" at the bottom of page
2. Developer documentation, select the "Fabric React" at the bottom of page
3. http://uifabricicons.azurewebsites.net/

I believe currently I can only use the icons in "Fabric Core" list. E.g I can use "AddNotes", but not "AddIn".

How can I use the icons in other sets?

I am using office-ui-fabric-REACT. I have following in the code:

```
import { initializeIcons } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icons";
initializeIcons();
```